# Los buscadores en react native se ocultan por el teclado en android

Tags: android, react-native

Estoy usando React Native y tengo en una pantalla con varios elementos. En un elemento al principio tengo un buscador que al seleccionar el teclado me tapa los resultados, pero me permite escribir. Pero al final de la pantalla tengo otro elemento con otro buscador y al seleccionar el teclado oculta totalmente ese elemento. Estoy usando KeyboardAvoidingView y ScrollView

Estoy usando Android

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    TouchableOpacity
} from "react-native";
import { Text, Button } from "react-native-elements";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons";

import DPicker from "../../components/DPicker";
import Picker from "../../components/Picker";
import PickerOther from "../../components/PickerOther";
import Loading from "../../components/Loading";
import ErrorLabel from "../../components/Error";
import Autoselect from "../../components/Autoselect";
import t from "../../utils/translation";
import formatDate from "../../utils/dates";

import { captureSpots, sources } from "../../data";

const navigationOptions = {
    title: t("report.defender")
};

const Defender = props => {
let nloading = true;

const {
    accountId,
    locationId,
    placeId,
    datetime,
    source,
    sourceOther,
    captureDatetime,
    captureSpot,
    captureSpotOther,
    captureAuthorId,
    captureAuthorOther,
    holdingPlaceId,
    holdingPlaceOther,
    locationOther,
    placeOther
} = props.screenProps.report;

const { accounts, authors, locations, places } = props.screenProps.selects;

const {
    handleChangeInput,
    handleChangePickerOther
} = props.screenProps.handlers;

const { nav, send, loading, isValid, errors } = props.screenProps;

let disabled = false;

return (
    <Fragment>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            keyboardVerticalOffset={20}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            behavior="position"
            enabled
        >
            <ScrollView
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
                style={styles.container}
                keyboardVerticalOffset={100}
            >
                <View style={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}>
                    {/* SECTION 1 */}
                    <Picker
                        label={t("field.label.accountId")}
                        items={accounts}
                        itemId={accountId}
                        disabled
                        handleChange={handleChangeInput("accountId")}
                    />

                    <PickerOther
                        label={t("field.label.locationId")}
                        items={locations}
                        itemId={locationId}
                        itemOther={locationOther}
                        handleChange={handleChangePickerOther(
                            "locationId",
                            "locationOther"
                        )}
                        handleOther={handleChangeInput("locationOther")}
                    />
                    {errors.includes("locationId") && (
                        <ErrorLabel message="*Requerido" />
                    )}

                    <Autoselect
                        items={places}
                        itemId={placeId}
                        label="placeId"
                        onChange={handleChangeInput}
                    />

                    {errors.includes("placeId") && (
                        <ErrorLabel message="*Requerido" />
                    )}



                    <DPicker
                        label={t("field.label.datetime")}
                        datetime={datetime ? datetime : formatDate()}
                        handleChange={handleChangeInput("datetime")}
                    />

                    <PickerOther
                        label={t("field.label.source")}
                        items={sources}
                        itemId={source}
                        itemOther={sourceOther}
                        handleChange={handleChangePickerOther(
                            "source",
                            "sourceOther"
                        )}
                        handleOther={handleChangeInput("sourceOther")}
                    />
                    {errors.includes("source") && (
                        <ErrorLabel message="*Requerido" />
                    )}
                    {/* SECTION 2 */}
                    <DPicker
                        label={t("field.label.captureDatetime")}
                        datetime={captureDatetime}
                        handleChange={handleChangeInput("captureDatetime")}
                    />

                    <PickerOther
                        label={t("field.label.captureSpot")}
                        items={captureSpots}
                        itemId={captureSpot}
                        itemOther={captureSpotOther}
                        handleChange={handleChangePickerOther(
                            "captureSpot",
                            "captureSpotOther"
                        )}
                        handleOther={handleChangeInput("captureSpotOther")}
                    />
                    <PickerOther
                        label={t("field.label.captureAuthorId")}
                        items={authors}
                        itemId={captureAuthorId}
                        itemOther={captureAuthorOther}
                        handleChange={handleChangePickerOther(
                            "captureAuthorId",
                            "captureAuthorOther"
                        )}
                        handleOther={handleChangeInput(
                            "captureAuthorOther"
                        )}
                    />

        <Autoselect
                        items={places}
                        itemId={holdingPlaceId}
                        label="holdingPlaceId"
                        onChange={handleChangeInput}
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        <View style={styles.btnLayout}>
            <Button
                icon={<Icon name="paper-plane" size={20} color="white" />}
                titleStyle={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
                title={t("button.send")}
                type="solid"
                disabled={!isValid || disabled}
                raised
                onPress={async () => {
                    disabled = await true;
                    await send("evaluation");
                }}
            />
            <Button
                icon={<Icon name="check" size={20} color="white" />}
                titleStyle={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
                title={t("button.draft")}
                type="solid"
                disabled={disabled}
                raised
                onPress={async () => {
                    disabled = await true;
                    await send("draft");
                }}
            />
        </View>
    </Fragment>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 16
},

section: {
    marginTop: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#cacaca",
    padding: 8
},
borderContainerInput: {
    marginTop: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "#cacaca"
},
borderInput: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0
},
title: {
    fontWeight: "bold"
},
btnLayout: {
    padding: 8,
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between"
},
ShowError: {
    color: "red",
    marginLeft: 5
}
});

Defender.navigationOptions = navigationOptions;

export default Defender;
```

Este es el primer elemento:

```
<Autoselect
        items={places}
        itemId={placeId}
        label="placeId"
        onChange={handleChangeInput}
    />
```

Este es el segundo elemento:

```
<Autoselect
     items={places}
     itemId={holdingPlaceId}
     label="holdingPlaceId"
     onChange={handleChangeInput}
/>
```

Comment: comparte el código por favor

Comment: Ya agregue. Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo usar: https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view
Te va salvar de muchos dolores de cabeza. Debes prestar mucha atención a la sección: `Android Support` ahí viene una recomendación del `AndroidManifest.xml` que dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr es la configuración que necesitas realizar.